# How to fetch a list inside a list using LINQ to Entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a requirement where i need to display a list in jquery DATATABLE. one of the column in a row will have multiple items (list).

So, in Busines Logic while fetching the DB details i'm trying to fetch a list which has another list in a row.

```
listTest = 
  (from TestA in context.Business
   join Status in context.BStatus 
       on TestA. BStatus_Id equals Status.ID
   join Prior in context.Priority 
       on TestA.Prior_ID equals Prior.ID into PriorityDetails
   from PrtryDT in PriorityDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new PModel
   {
       Id = TestA.ID,
       Name = TestA.NM,
       PriorityEvaluatedOnTS = TestA.PRI_EVAL_ON_TS,
       //RequestPriority = i need to write a linq here to fetch a list for RequestPriority
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: You're looking for a sub-select, using navigation properties. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754058/linq-to-entities-with-subselect-in-select-part).

Comment: What about `RequestPriority = PriorityDetails`?